# Check real file size while streaming files with FileItemStream

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets, file-upload, apache-commons-fileupload

I'm writing an API using Spring + apache commons file upload.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/

There is a problem that I faced. I need to validate a file size. If it's bigger then the one that I configure, user should get an error.
For now, I implemented the upload without this check and it looks like this:

```
public ResponseEntity insertFile(@PathVariable Long profileId, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
    FileItemIterator uploadItemIterator = upload.getItemIterator(request);
    if (!uploadItemIterator.hasNext()) {
        throw new FileUploadException("FileItemIterator was empty");
    }
    while (uploadItemIterator.hasNext()) {
        FileItemStream fileItemStream = uploadItemIterator.next();
        if (fileItemStream.isFormField()) {
            continue;
        }
       //do stuff
    }
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

It does exactly what I need. It doesn't require me to get file loaded completely to the memory. I use InputStream that I got  to perform further transfer to another service. Eventually, I don't have file loaded to the memory completely at any point of the time. 
However, that prevents me from getting the total number of bites that were loaded.

Is there a way to handle such validation without downloading file completely or saving it somewhere?

I tried FileItem, but it does require complete loading of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServletFileUpload has a method setSizeMax that control the max file size accepted for each request. To mitigate memory consumption issues you can use a DiskFileFactory to set disk file storing for larger files. You must always get the files cause trusting in headers only is not reliable but I think this will do the job :)

Comment: This one does the job. Thanks! 
I understand all the importance of not trusting to the headers. 
However, in my case, I have no options. The service that I transfer to should fail on that, my job here is just to give user a user-friendly exception and do not perform all additional work while transferring the file.

Comment: It appears that the exception happens only when part of the file is processed. So, if max size is 5 GB I need to process first 5GB to understand whether the file fits my requirements or not. I was hopping that there should be a way to say it on the stage of validation(before uploading)

Comment: You can check it on the client of the service before sending it. Is it you that develop too? HTML +JavaScript right? Is it in upload form?

Comment: Our front end uses JS. Basically React. 
Yes. That's possible, but is that a good practice? I mean someone can put a big load on the system streaming files to the backend without using front-end. Just using rest API. Yes, files won't be saved, However, it will make a load on the servers.

Comment: If you have an appache server in front you can add a LimitRequestBody directive in order to control the max size of the requests it accepts. For 5gB <Directory "/.../.../uploads">
    LimitRequestBody 5242880000 
</Directory>

Comment: This last option would reject the payload on your front servers and keep you back servers ok. An HTTP 413 would be fired by the apache when the limit is reached. I think the upload would always be done by a direct Rest client but for that you would have to go with some other DOS protection...

Comment: Thanks, will use option with apache server.